# Account upgrade functionaility from legacy to Lumens still not working

Tags: error, upgrade

Even after repeated requests this issue isn't resolved by stellar. Moderator moves my query to a old resolved post which does not have a satisfactory answer.

P.S.: Please urgently solve this issue as many users are unable to access / upgrade their accounts and this problem is lasting since last 3 weeks or more. Please do not just move my post to some other duplicate post which does not resolve this issue. I have made repeated requests over last 2 weeks but no resolve or acknowledgement by the stellar team yet. Please do address for everyone's kind benefit. This is not spam email as some other user has mentioned, is is a genuine account upgrade issue on Stellar official website.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a scam. Stellar will never require you to "upgrade" your wallet. The native token of Stellar already is named Lumens (XLM), it's been over 5 years since they the name was changed from stellars to lumens.

This is a trick to get you to reveal you're secret key. If you did, then unfortunately your money is gone.